# Proof of the Nine Lemma using the Snake Lemma

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification, exact-sequence

I attempted to prove the [$\it 3\times3$ *Lemma* (or *Nine Lemma*)](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/3x3+lemma). First off, I am well aware how to proceed by means of diagram chase and I know how to prove the $\it 3\times3$ *Lemma* doing so. However, I am interested in an alternative way using the [*Snake Lemma*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/snake+lemma) as suggested in [P. Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter $\it 0$*](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/algebra-chapter-0) (exercise III.$7.15$ for reference, all appearing objects are taken to be $R$-modules over a fixed commutative, unital ring $R$ and $0$ is the trivial module).

To keep this post self-contained, let me state the *Snake Lemma*

> **Lemma** (*Snake Lemma*). Given a commutative diagram
>
> [image]
>   where the rows are exact, there is an exact sequence
>   $$
> 0\longrightarrow\ker\lambda\longrightarrow\ker\mu\longrightarrow\ker\nu\overset{\delta}\longrightarrow{\rm coker}~\lambda\longrightarrow{\rm coker}~\mu\longrightarrow{\rm coker}~\nu\longrightarrow0
> $$

The $\it 3\times3$ *Lemma* reads as

> **Lemma** ($\it 3\times3$ *Lemma*). Given a commutative diagram
>
> [image]
>   where the rows and the two rightmost columns are exact, then the leftmost column is exact.

*Proof.* We need to prove four things:

1. $\lambda_2\circ\lambda_1=0$
2. $\lambda_1$ is monic
3. $\lambda_2$ is epi
4. $\ker\lambda_2={\rm im}~\lambda_1$

$1.$ By the commutativity of the diagramm $\gamma_1\circ(\lambda_2\circ\lambda_1)=(\mu_2\circ\mu_1)\circ\alpha_1$, but as the second column is exact $\mu_2\circ\mu_1=0$ and therefore $\gamma_1\circ(\lambda_2\circ\lambda_1)=0$. Since $\gamma_1$ is monic (as the last row is exact) it follows that $\lambda_2\circ\lambda_1=0$.

$2.$ By the commutativity of the diagram $\mu_1\circ\alpha_1=\beta_1\circ\lambda_1$. But as $\mu_1$ and $\alpha_1$ are monic by exactness of the rows and the second column it follows that $\lambda_1$ is monic aswell.

$3.$ Applying the *Snake Lemma* to the last two rows gives an exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow\ker\lambda_2\longrightarrow\ker\mu_2\longrightarrow\ker\nu_2\overset{\delta}\longrightarrow{\rm coker}~\lambda_2\longrightarrow{\rm coker}~\mu_2\longrightarrow{\rm coker}~\nu_2\longrightarrow0$$
As $\mu_2$ and $\nu_2$ are epi their respective cokernels are trivial. Also, by exactness of the rightmost columns $\ker\mu_2={\rm im}~\mu_1$ and $\ker\nu_2={\rm im}~\nu_1$. While leaving out unneeded parts we obtain the exact sequence
$${\rm im}~\mu_1\overset{f}\longrightarrow{\rm im}~\nu_1\overset{\delta}\longrightarrow{\rm coker}~\lambda_2\overset{t}\longrightarrow0$$
On the other hand, given $x\in{\rm im}~\nu_1$ there exist an $y\in M_0$ such that $(\nu_1\circ\alpha_2)(y)=x$ as $\alpha_2$ is epi. But then $\beta_2(\mu_1(x))=y$ by commutativity of the diagram and thus the connecting arrow ${\rm im}~\mu_1\longrightarrow{\rm im}~\nu_1$ has to be epi aswell (!). As the sequence is exact, it follows that $\ker\delta={\rm im}~f={\rm im}~\nu_1$ and $\ker t={\rm im}~\delta=0$. But then $t$ is an isomorphism as it is clearly epi and monic by the aforegoing argumentation. Therefore ${\rm coker}~\lambda_2=0$, that is $\lambda_2$ is epi.

$4.$ I have a vague idea. We have the following exact sequence by the *Snake Lemma*

[image]
From here it should be somehow possible to identifty $\ker\lambda_2$ with ${\rm im}~\lambda_1$ but I do not know how *without* using a diagram chase.

> $\textbf{Q1}:$ Is the proof of $3.$ fine as it stands? I am not sure whether I can conclude that $f$ like this, as the construction of a pre-image for every $x\in{\rm im}~\nu_1$ in ${\rm im}~\mu_1$ does not refer to $f$ *directly*. On the other hand, I do know that $f$ is uniquely defined by the universal property of $\ker\mu_2$ and I think that should to the trick.
>   $\textbf{Q2}:$ How can the proof be finished using the *Snake Lemma*? I am not sure how continue in step $4.$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the whole thing follwos from the snake lemma. One would need to argue that you can replace the left most column with  $ 0 \to \ker \alpha_1 \to \ker \beta_1 \to \ker \gamma_1 \to 0$. Then, applying the sname lemma will give you what you need. Then apply the snake lemma to obtain the sequence $0 \to \ker \alpha_1 \to \ker \beta_1 \to \ker \gamma_1 \to \operatorname{coker} \alpha_2=0$

Comment: Ah I found a reference for this type of argument. See lemma 2.4 [here](https://math.mit.edu/~phaine/files/Diagram_Chases.pdf) +1 by the way for all of the detail :). To be fair, the "hard part" of this argument is proving lemma 2.3 above, which is that such identifications with (co)kernels are natural in morphisms of chain complexes

Comment: @AndresMejia Well, that finally explains the hint Aluffi gave ("You can avoid a diagram chase by applying the snake lemma; fpr this, you will need to turn the diagram by $90^\circ$"); but I wasn't sure what this hint tried to point out. Anyway, thank you kindly!

Comment: Haha! I was going to suggest that you turn it counterclockwise by 90 degrees, but I didn't want to be annoying. If you would like a different write up for proof for this (not using snake lemma), I'm pretty sure I can supply it, but only because I found an old write up. A hint is that it is a long and annoying diagram chase.

Comment: @AndresMejia I've gone all through the details of the diagram chase and that's why I'm *especially* interested in an alternative `^^'` Feel free to write down the general idea given in the link as an answer! (what is called Lemma $2.3$ there is actually featured as exercise III.$7.3$ in Aluffi).

Comment: @Rob Pratt I agree that the "exact-sequence" tag is appropriate here. On the other hand, as the question is specifically aimed at *not* using a diagram chase for the proof, I removed the "diagram-chase" tag again (and not included it in the first place either).